# R Shiny Shinyapps.io magick_image_write_frame: R: cache resources exhausted Error Message

Tags: r, shiny, imagemagick, shinyapps

I have an app hosted in shinyapps.io and recently I'm getting the following error message when running it, which leads to the termination of the app: `` Warning: Error in magick_image_write_frame: R: cache resources exhausted `' @ error/cache.c/OpenPixelCache/4083 ``

I found some explanations on how to increase the cache of Magick. Unfortunately there is no solution how to solve this for shinyapps.io. I also increased the instance size in Shinyapps to 8GB with the same issue.

I am thankful for any advice and solution!

Comment: Any solution so far ?